# I am currently doing the 'Build a LAMP website' project and mousepad is not working

Tags: pi-3

I am a newbie to Raspberry pi and I am unable to continue, I am currently at:
https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/lamp-web-server-with-wordpress/2
and in need to use the following command:'sudo mousepad index.html'. If I use that command, no matter in which directory, I get the following response: 'sudo: mousepad: command not found'.
What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Note that `mousepad` is just a text editor, which can be substituted with `leafpad`, `gedit`, `mcedit`, `nano`, or even hardcore stuff like `vi` or `emacs`, whichever you happen to have installed and are familiar with. I think `leafpad` is there by default, and it's yet another MS Notepad clone just like `mousepad`.

If you want to edit HTML regularly, note that `gedit`, `mcedit`,  `nano`, `vim` and `emacs` will highlight the HTML syntax for you.

Also, `sudo update-alternatives --config editor` allows you to pick a default editor on your system which then will be started when you use `editor` as a command name (e.g. `sudo editor index.html`).

Answer (score 0):

Install the program with

`sudo apt install mousepad`

Perhaps you missed a configuration step or are not using the expected distribution.